# How to open WhatsApp Mac from the command line or javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, command-line, whatsapp

I can open the WhatsApp mac app from the browser with a formed link like this:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+12125551212

How can I achieve the same thing from javascript or nodejs or from the command line?

We can do # open -a https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+12125551212
from the command line, but it just sends us to the browser... how to skip the browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Puppeteer** library of Node JS.

**Puppeteer** is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. Puppeteer runs headless by default, but can be configured to run full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromium.

**Headless means it will not open in browser, instead will run in background.**

To use Puppeteer in your project, run:

```
npm i puppeteer --save
```

Here is a link to similar project.

[WhatsApp from CLI](https://github.com/sarfraznawaz2005/whatspup)

Comment: Thank you, both of these are different from what i'm seeking to do, but also maybe useful.

Comment: @fotoflo How it is different??

Comment: Sorry to be clear,  i want to launch the mac app with the given number as an argument, as given in the link.    These two are controlling the browser.